# Class active when on page using php

Tags: php, html, css

I have an include file that includes the header and footer of my site. But in the header I use an active class to let the menu-item change when on that page. How can you achieve this using one include file? With PHP?

I found this:

index.php

```
<?php $page == 'one'; include('includes/header.php'); ?>
```

header.php

```
<li>
      <a <?php echo ($page == 'one') ? "class='active'" : ""; ?> 
             href="contact.php">Contact</a>/</li>
```

But it's not changing, when I just used the class on every page seperately, it worked.

Comment: Try to change your variable-declaration in index.php to $page = 'one'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index.php

```
<?php $page = 'one'; include('includes/header.php'); ?>
```

$page = 'one'. "==" is a comparison operator http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Header.php

```
<li><a href="#"<?php if($page == 'one'){ echo ' class="active"';}?>>LINK</a></li>
```

I think is more clean like that

Comment: Thanks! That worked, but only for the last one and the first one?? Any idea why that is? The code is exactly the same apart from the names (four, five, six e.g.)

Comment: Nevermind lol, I found what it was. I added the code in the place of the footer (doh) Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

just move the `echo` to correct place(s), because your syntax is not correct

Like this;

```
<li>
  <a 
    <?php
      echo( $page == 'one'  ? "class='active'" : ""); 
     ?> 
   href="contact.php">Contact</a>
/
</li>
```

And also you should correct this in include.php

```
$page = 'one';
```

with single  "="  sign

Comment: You need `(` and `)` around the `if` statement; `($page == 'one')`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
     $page = 'one'; 
     include('includes/header.php'); 
 ?>
```

$page =1; not $page == 1; because it is assignment of a variable.

Rest of the code is fine.